# Rudin's Complex and Real Analysis, problem 1.9.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

In a more explicit proof of part (a), how would I show that $\Phi(x,y)=x+yi$ is continuous using purely topological properties?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*: One way to show that the function $\Phi\colon \mathbf{R}^2\to \mathbf{C}$ is continuous is by showing that the preimage of an open disk in $\mathbf{C}$ is open in $\mathbf{R}^2$.

The preimage of $\{z\in \mathbf{C}\colon \lvert z - a\rvert < \varepsilon\}$ is not too difficult to write down explicitly considering that $\Phi$ is the natural bijection between $\mathbf{R}^2$ and $\mathbf{C}$.

Comment: Would the pre image be $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2:|x-f^{-1}(a)|<\epsilon\}$? Which is clearly an open ball?

Comment: @SamKirkiles I think you’ve changed notation somewhat here, but if you can show that $\lvert \Phi(x, y) - a \rvert = \lvert (x, y) - \Phi^{-1}(a)\rvert$ then yes!

Comment: Ok assuming that $a=a_1+b_1i$ $|\Phi(x,y)−a|=|\Phi(x,y)-(a_1+b_1i)|=|(x-a_1)+(y-b_1)i|=\sqrt{|x-a_1|^2+(y-b_1)^2}=|(x,y)-(a_1,b_1)|=|(x,y)-\Phi^{-1}(a_1+b_1i)|=|(x,y)-\Phi^{-1}(a)|$ Using the fact that the distance function on $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R^2}$ is the same is this correct?

Comment: @SamKirkiles You got it! So, this tells us that the preimage of the open $\varepsilon$-disk centered at $a$ is the open $\varepsilon$-ball centered at $\Phi^{-1}(a)$.

Comment: thank you so much for your help!